# How to open MS Project file(s) from Enterprise projectserver using VBA (2013)

Tags: vba, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I did search many times to find a proper solution, but till today I didn't find a proper solution for my function. Target is to open a schedule from the server using VBA either from within MS Project or MS Excel using only part of the mpp filename.
We do have a ProjectID for each schedule. Unfortunately, this is only part of the file name and the rest even changes from time to time:
Example: ProjectID_Department_Projectname

With FileOpenEx I can easily open a file from the server using full file name. I wonder now if there is a way to use part of the name.
-Is there a function to open a file using placeholders?
or alternatively
-Does anyone know how to loop through all files on project server or retrieve a list of files?

Comment: It can be done by accessing the reporting database to get the list of projects. See this [msdn forum answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1179bb5-4a33-4418-8478-4d4aba84b2a4/loop-through-all-files-on-project-server-2010-using-vba?forum=project2010custprog)